# How to write value in array during definition

Tags: c

how to put value during array definition:

```
int array[2][3][4] = {{},{{},{2}}};
```

I want to put value in array[1][1][1]. Above result is array[1][1][0]

Comment: Read a basic `C` book or use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C99, just use:

```
int array[2][3][4] = { [1][1][1] = 2 };
```

and be done.